# How can I make my swing graphics project have a higher FPS(frames per second for anyone who doesn't know what it means)?

Tags: java, graphics

I started remaking my graphics engine and i have a problem with repainting the VolatileImage on the JFrame, i added an FPS counter and when it is in full-screen it only gets to around 250 or 280 FPS even though i have the loop in a new thread and I'm only drawing 2 dots on the screen.
Here is the code for the init and render functions in the Window class, might be a bit unorganized:
`

```
public int render() {
    frame.getGraphics().drawImage(vImg, 0, 0, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), null);
    totalFrames++;
    if (System.nanoTime() > lastFPScheck + 1000000000) {
        lastFPScheck = System.nanoTime();
        currentFPS = totalFrames;
        totalFrames = 0;
    }
    if (vImg.validate(gc) == VolatileImage.IMAGE_OK) {
        vImg = gc.createCompatibleVolatileImage(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
    }
    if (debugging()) {
        frame.setTitle(title + "[FPS: " + currentFPS + "]");
    }
    graphics = (Graphics2D)vImg.getGraphics();

    graphics.setColor(bg_color);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
    return currentFPS;
}

public void repaint_buffer() {
    frame.getContentPane().getGraphics().drawImage(vImg, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, null);
}

public void init(int width,
                 int height,
                 String title,
                 Color bg_color,
                 Consumer<Void> onDestroy) {
    this.canvasWidth = width;
    this.canvasHeight = height;
    this.is_open = true;
    this.title = title;
    this.bg_color = bg_color;

    this.frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            onDestroy.accept(null);
        }
    });
    this.frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowResized(WindowEvent e) {
            vImg = gc.createCompatibleVolatileImage(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
        }
    });
    this.frame.setLayout(null);
    this.frame.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    this.frame.addKeyListener(keyInput);
    this.frame.setResizable(true);
    this.frame.setLocation(-7, 0);
    this.frame.setTitle(title);
    this.frame.setVisible(true);

    gc = this.frame.getGraphicsConfiguration();
    vImg = gc.createCompatibleVolatileImage(this.frame.getWidth(), this.frame.getHeight());
    this.graphics = (Graphics2D) vImg.getGraphics();
}
```

`
and here is the code from the Main class, the GraphicsManager object only contains the set_pixel function which sets the color and draws a rectangle at the given position with a size of 1x1 pixels:

```
package obsidian.core;
import obsidian.core.Window;

import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    private static void on_destroy() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Window window = new Window();
        window.init(Window.get_max_size().width, Window.get_max_size().height, "title", new Color(0, 0, 0), destroy -> on_destroy());

        GraphicsManager gm = new GraphicsManager(window);
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(window.is_open()) {
                    window.render();

                    gm.draw_pixel(0.5, 0.5, new Color(255, 0, 0));
                    gm.draw_pixel(0, 0, new Color(255, 255, 255));
                    
                    System.out.println(window.get_current_fps());
                }
            }
        });

        t.start();

    }
}
```

I tried removing the VolatileImage and directly drawing on the frame but the filling of the image makes it glitchy but it got to about 2000 FPS and IntelliJ IDEA couldn't keep up. The only solution I could find to make it run faster is removing the VolatileImage and draw directly to the frame. Didn't work ;-;
Can anyone help me with this? Thank you

Comment: Why do you want it to run faster? How many times per second do you think your monitor refreshes its image?

Comment: I added an fps counter that also prints it in the console, at start its under 200 and by the end it barely gets to 240 or 250 when at max size, when i make it small it can get up to 9000 to 10000 fps

Comment: `frame.getGraphics()` is NOT how you should be doing this, you're fighting the existing passive paint system and in this context, you couldn't guarantee when something is actually painted to the screen.  Swing is also NOT thread safe, this means you shouldn't be updating the UI or any state the UI depends on from out side the content of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: For more details, look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more details

Comment: Sooo, should i use normal Frame object? It misses some stuff that JFrame has though

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to a `JFrame` - it's complicated and messy.  Better to start with a `JPanel`.  I got a Swing `Timer` to paint at roughly 800fps and a `BufferStrategy` to between 680-711fps using a 1 millisecond delay between frames or, if I go hell for leather, ~8500fps ... although I would argue if that's an "accurate" representation or just how fast I can make a thread loop

Comment: I would also suggest having a look at [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities
](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) which will give you direct access to the paint process

Comment: Ok, i tried having a JPanel in the frame and then draw the VolatileImage on it but it made the program even slower. Could you maybe write a small example? I understand it better when its in code. Thanks for the answer though. Will look into it and see if that fixes it

Answer (score 0):

## Swing "passive" painting

This makes use of a [Swing `Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

~170fps

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Timer timer;
        private Instant lastTick;
        private int fps = 0;

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.stop();
            }
            timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                private int frameCount = 0;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (lastTick != null) {
                        Duration duration = Duration.between(lastTick, Instant.now());
                        if (duration.toMillis() >= 1000) {
                            lastTick = Instant.now();
                            fps = frameCount;
                            frameCount = 0;
                        } else {
                            frameCount++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        lastTick = Instant.now();
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.stop();
            }
            timer = null;
            super.removeNotify();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fillOval(20, 20, 20, 20);
            g2d.fillOval(40, 40, 20, 20);

            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            String text = Integer.toString(fps);
            g2d.drawString(text, 10, fm.getAscent());
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

## "Active" painting via a `BufferStrategy`

~680fps

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class Other {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Other();
    }

    public Other() {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        MainCanvas canvas = new MainCanvas();
        frame.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class MainCanvas extends Canvas {

        private Thread thread;
        private AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        private int fps;

        public MainCanvas() {
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            stop();
            super.removeNotify();
        }

        public void start() {
            stop();
            run();
        }

        protected void stop() {
            if (running.get()) {
                running.set(false);
            }
            thread = null;
        }

        protected void run() {
            stop();

            running.set(true);
            thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                private Instant lastTick;
                private int frameCount;

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (running.get()) {
                        if (lastTick != null) {
                            Duration duration = Duration.between(lastTick, Instant.now());
                            if (duration.toMillis() >= 1000) {
                                lastTick = Instant.now();
                                fps = frameCount;
                                frameCount = 0;
                            } else {
                                frameCount++;
                            }
                        } else {
                            lastTick = Instant.now();
                        }
                        render();
                        // Comment out these lines and see where it takes you
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Other.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }

        protected void render() {
            BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
            while (bs == null) {
                bs = getBufferStrategy();
            }
            do {
                // The following loop ensures that the contents of the drawing buffer
                // are consistent in case the underlying surface was recreated
                do {
                    // Get a new graphics context every time through the loop
                    // to make sure the strategy is validated
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();

                    g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                    // Render to graphics
                    // ...
                    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g2d.fillOval(20, 20, 20, 20);
                    g2d.fillOval(40, 40, 20, 20);

                    FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
                    String text = Integer.toString(fps);
                    g2d.drawString(text, 10, fm.getAscent());
                    // Dispose the graphics
                    g2d.dispose();

                    // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer contents
                    // were restored
                } while (bs.contentsRestored());

                // Display the buffer
                bs.show();

                // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer was lost
            } while (bs.contentsLost());
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }
    }
}
```

## Disclaimer

This is by far a "scientific" example and is intended simply as a demonstration between passive and active rendering workflows

Comment: Damn, my engine will need some tweaks but i can just make a Consumer argument for the rendering and run it in the loop. This is amazing. Thank you so much